# Did Pevara prevaricate?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

Re-listening to *A Memory Of Light*. I might add the direct quote if it helps the question, but it's squirreled away somewhere so it's not handy right now.

Anyway, I don't think this is a spoiler, but in Chapter 4 there's a scene in which Pevara Sedai has one of the Ashaman bound up in air and deafened.  Emarin tells her to let the hearing block unravel in such a way that the captive can hear what he's saying, but make it seem like it's due to being tied off and unraveling.  He then starts talking (an act) and at one point pauses and says, "he can't hear us, can he?" By this point it was fairly clear to me as a reader that Emarin was expecting that the captive could hear and it seemed to me this was after he'd be able to hear as well (otherwise the rest of the act makes no sense).  Despite that, Pevara says, "No".

This seems like either a) the weaves hadn't been unraveled yet and Emarin continued on anyway, or b) Pevara was lying and the captive could hear.

In the case of a), Emarin's ruse doesn't make sense, so I feel like Pevara must have lied, but shortly after that scene they make it clear she's still subject to the 3 Oaths.  So what am I missing? Did she lie or was it something else?

Comment: Love the title :-D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> “An Aes Sedai never lies, but the truth she speaks, may not be the truth you think you hear.”
>
> <sub>Tam al'Thor - The Eye of the World</sub>

The way Emarin phrases his question to Pevara is ambiguous, and involves a bit of word play:

> Emarin turned to their captive.  "He cannot hear what we say?"

Emarin has a negative in his question "cannot", and Pevara answers with a negative "No". These two negatives cancel each other out, meaning the answer is a postitve: **He can hear**.

So Pevara did not lie, she told the truth in a way only Aes Sedai could.

Comment: Damn, how did I miss that?  Great answer, thanks!

Comment: You always need to watch for those sneaky witches.